# Django: Strange thing going on with clean_

Tags: python, django

so this is really weird. when I do clean_email, i get an error, and then it prints "None" for emailConfirm. When I do clean_emailConfirm, it works perfectly. for some reason I am getting different results, even though the only thing i am changing is the name of the function (clean_email to clean_emailConfirm). anyone got any ideas why?

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'First Name','required':True}))
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Last Name','required':True}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email','required':True}))
    emailConfirm = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email','required':True}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
    datetime = forms.DateTimeInput()

    class Meta:
        model=SignUp
        fields=['fname','lname','email','emailConfirm','password']

    # def clean_email(self):    
    #   email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    #   emailConfirm=self.cleaned_data.get('emailConfirm')
    #   if email != emailConfirm:
    #       #print(cleaned_data2)
    #       print(email)
    #       print(emailConfirm)
    #       raise forms.ValidationError("Your two emails must be the same!")
    #   else:
    #       return email
    def clean_emailConfirm(self):   
        email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        emailConfirm=self.cleaned_data.get('emailConfirm')
        if emailConfirm != email:
            #print(cleaned_data2)
            print(email)
            print(emailConfirm)
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your two emails must be the same!")
        else:
            print(emailConfirm)
            print(email)
            return email
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't cross validate fields in `clean_foo` methods, because not all fields' `clean_foo` methods are called when you are in one of them, so there might be some values of the form that are not populated yet. It should be done in `clean` method. [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) very explicitly documented this:

> By the time the form’s clean() method is called, all the individual
>   field clean methods will have been run (the previous two sections), so
>   self.cleaned_data will be populated with any data that has survived so
>   far. So you also need to remember to allow for the fact that the
>   fields you are wanting to validate might not have survived the initial
>   individual field checks.